# C# A Noob "Trapped" in Polymorphism

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism

Allright, so I have the following problem.
I have the following hierarchy of classes that inherit from each other

```
Character ->     Melee    -> Warrior
                          -> Assassin
                          -> Knight
          -> Spellcasters -> Mage
                          -> Druid
                          -> Necromancer
```

Thanks to Inheritance and Polymorphism I was able to extract almost every piece of redundant code out of the base classes (warrior, assassin....). Character, Melee and Spellcaster are all abstract.

So I proceeded with writing my logic, the idea is to have two teams Melee and Spellcasters that fight with each other until one of the teams wins.
And this last condition made things very bad, very quickly.

So I created one List which holds all 6 derived type charaters, then I distribute them accordingly to two other lists List and List with loops (my rationale was, if I ever wanted to add more characters into the fight I just need to add them in the initial list and the rest will be handled automatically)

The problem that I have is that apparently (and I should've expected it) I lost access to all of my properties/methods in my derived classes (melee, spellcater, warrior etc).

What I tried to do is add a property DeadTeam in both Melee and Spellcaster classes that I would use to track if either of the teams lost the battle, of course I had no access to this property...

So how should I restructure my logic, to still have the flexibility that Polymorphism gave me, not write a ton of code and be able to access my most derived classes without conversions?

```
class EntryPoint
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Random rng = new Random();
        int turnCounter = 0;
        bool gameOver = false;

        List<Character> characters = new List<Character>()
        {
            new Warrior(),
            new Knight(),
            new Assassin(),
            new Mage(),
            new Necromancer(),
            new Druid()
        };

        List<Character> meleeTeam = new List<Character>();
        List<Character> spellTeam = new List<Character>();

        foreach (var character in characters)
        {
            if (character is Melee)
            {
                meleeTeam.Add(character);
            }
            else if (character is Spellcaster)
            {
                spellTeam.Add(character);
            }
        }



        while (!gameOver)
        {
            //meleeTeam[turnCounter].Attack(spellTeam[rng.Next(0, spellTeam.Count)]);
            //spellTeam[turnCounter].Attack(meleeTeam[rng.Next(0, meleeTeam.Count)]);

            turnCounter++;

            if (turnCounter == 3)
            {
                turnCounter = 0;
            }

            gameOver = CheckForWinner(meleeTeam, spellTeam);
        }

    }

    private static bool CheckForWinner(List<Character> meleeTeam, List<Character> spellTeam)
    {

        bool allMeleeDead = true;
        bool allSpellDead = true;

        foreach (var character in meleeTeam)
        {
            if (character.IsAlive == true)
            {
                allMeleeDead = false;
            }
        }

        foreach (var character in spellTeam)
        {
            if (character.IsAlive == true)
            {
                allSpellDead = false;
            }
        }

        if (allMeleeDead)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Spellcaster team wins!");

            return true;
        }
        else if (allSpellDead)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Melee team wins!");

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The CheckForWinner method that I Created will obviously do the job, but its a workaround that I dont want to keep, its not even a workaround since down the road I would still need something else from my derived classes and I still wont have access to it. I figured this issue when it occured to me that I would have no information out of this method about wether a team is dead or alive

Another obvious issue, I wanted to make my meleeTeam and spellTeam lists to be of Melee and Spellcaster type, but of course that was not possible either.

P.S. I am aware that I can type cast them into their derived types, but that will quadruple my code, and this is what I am trying to avoid.

P.S. 2

I have changed my meleeteam and spellteams to  and  and I typecasted the items from characters list while adding them to these two lists, this seemed to do the trick, and I completely rewrote the rest of the code that I pasted above. Apart from that, this still doesnt give me access to my most derived classes, but I dont need it for now anyway, seems like theres no way around writing code for each type when the time comes:)

Answer (score 0):

Your lists are of type `Character` and type `Character` doesn't know anything about properties and method of derived classes.

You should cast objects in list to particular derived type:

```
var testMelee = meleeTeam[0] as Melee; 

if (testMelee != null)
{
    // now testMelee is of type Melee and has property DeadTeam (or other properties declared in Character and Melee types) 
    testMelee.DeadTeam = yourValue; // ok, there is such property
}
```

If you want all properties of `Warrior/Assasin/...` then you should cast to this type:

```
var testWarrior = meleeTeam[0] as Warrior; 

if (testWarrior != null)
{
    // now testWarrior is of type Warrior and has property DeadTeam (or other properties declared in Character, Melee and Warrior types)        
}
```

If you use C# 7 or higher then code can be changed to:

```
if (meleeTeam[0] as Warrior testWarrior)
{
    // now testWarrior is of type Warrior and has property DeadTeam (or other properties declared in Character, Melee and Warrior types)        
}
```

Also, in your post there is:

> What I tried to do is add a property DeadTeam in both Melee and
>   Spellcaster classes

There is no need to declare same property in both classes. You can simply declare this property in `Character` class and all derived classes can access it (if it is not private).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I am aware that I can type cast them, but that will probably quadruple my code, and this is what I am trying to avoid. Instead of having two rows of code in my while loop that will handle the fighting, I will have 6 ifs and a whole lot of more code handling type casting and character specific stuff. I want to keep the tidyness of polymorphism and still be able to easily access my derived properties/methods.

Comment: @Darkbound, but you can't access properties in base class type object that are declared in derived classes. You should either cast to needed object or consider about another way of storing objects in collection.

Comment: Precisely, I just dont know what that "other way" is, thats what I am trying to figure out:)

Comment: @Darkbound, to my mind, casting is the better way, but maybe I'm wrong

Comment: It will just add way too much code, I dont know if its possible to do it in any other way, but I want to do this as cleanly as possible... lets see what the others have to say, if there is even a way to do this...

Comment: I changed my melee and spell team lists to <Melee> and <Spellcaster> and type casting characters to (Melee) and (Spellcaster) while adding them seems to do the trick. eg. meleeTeam.Add((Melee)characters[0]) where characters[0] is a Warrior.

Answer (score 0):

> What I tried to do is add a property DeadTeam in both Melee and Spellcaster classes that I would use to track if either of the teams lost the battle, of course I had no access to this property...

These classes should not be the ones worrying about wether the whole team that they belong to is dead or not (that is the responsibility of the code related to teams - team class hint hint). The character class should have a method for determining if that particular character is dead(f.ex: public bool isAlive()) and you should do your "is whole team dead?" logic in a loop that loops through the characters in the team and says "yup, they're dead" if there are no alive characters in it.

In Code:

```
public abstract class Character
{
    ...
    public bool isAlive();
}

...
bool allDead = true;
foreach(Character char in spellteam)
{
    if(Character.isAlive())
    {
        allDead = false;
        break;
    }
}

if(allDead)
{
    //Do whatever you need to do when everyone is dead.
}
```

In general, you will want to avoid having to do the kind of type testing you are doing in your code by restructuring and recreating the abstractions that are forcing you to have the current structure.

An example of this is having the spellcaster and melee classes - you will never be able to have a class that is both a spellcaster and a melee and not because you said that in your game, there are no classes that are both, but because you structure your game in such a way that it becomes impossible.

Perhaps simply have actions for the kinds of things you want to do (either just have DoAction(actiontype), Attack() or even just TakeYourTurn()) in the base class and let the implementation of the class worry about what the final action is (as that knows which actions are available to it).

This way you can have whatever kinds of teams you want without limitations based on their actions - you can still use the caster/melee teams if you want, but without the limitations on possible future additions that currently exist.